# Creating Multiple PDF's from Google Sheets from a client list

Tags: google-sheets, pdf, mail-merge

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with logged times for projects. I need the data from each client to create a PDF with their times displayed. See attached image. This example has four clients, so I will need an automation to create four PDF's with times displayed. Two sample PDF's were created (on the right hand side of the image) to show how I need the information displayed. I can create the letter template myself which will be used by the automation to autofill on demand.

[image: Sample Sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is an exact copy of [Creating Multiple PDF's from Google Sheets from a client list](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/219317255). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: I also posted on another forum, also without luck.

Comment: The question has an accepted answer at [Creating Multiple PDF's from Google Sheets from a client list](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/219317255).